# XPATH - how to pick up text in each html element regardless of classes

Tags: xpath

I am trying to grab some content from webpages that are not structured in a uniform fashion. What I want to do is tell the XPATH to grab any content within html tags in the order it sees them and return the results, without having to specify div names etc, as they are different and not very uniform.

So I need to know how to just say 'return any html content in the order that it's found from within tags, regardless of whether they are classes, ems, strong tags etc. The only experience I have had with XPATH is to specify actual div names, example:

```
//div[@id='tab_info']
```

Comment: DOM has a tree structure so no worry about orders. What you need I think is something like `//body/*[text()]`

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
string(/)
```

will return the string value of the entire XML or HTML document.  That is, it'll return a single string of all of the text in document order, as requested.